# Erro webpack com bootstrap-loader

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, react, módulo-ecmascript, webpack

Estou com dificuldades para implementar o bootstrap-loader no webpack. Recebo está saída de erro no console:

> ERROR in
>   ./~/css-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./~/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.styles.loader.js!./~/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js
>   Module build failed: undefined ^
>         File to import not found or unreadable: ../../app/assets/styles/bootstrap/pre-customizations.scss Parent style
>   sheet: stdin
>         in C:\Users\rapha\Projetos\components\node_modules\bootstrap-loader\no-op.js
>   (line 2, column 1)  @
>   ./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./~/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.styles.loader.js!./~/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js
>   4:14-164

Este é meu arquivo webpack.config.js:

```
'use strict'
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: [
        'bootstrap-loader',
        path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'app')
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/static/'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            include: /src/,
            loader: 'babel'
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss']
        }, {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss', 'sass']
        }, {
            test: /bootstrap-sass\/assets\/javascripts\//,
            loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery'
        }]
    },
    postcss: [autoprefixer]
}
```

Alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

Ao que parece vc deve estar usando um require('../../app/assets/styles/bootstrap/pre-customizations.scss') em algum lugar. O problema é que a partir do arquivo que você está usando ele não localiza... tente verificar o caminho informado